# Oracle database dbms_ldap with TLS (LDAP over TLS aka starttls) on 389

Tags: database, oracle, active-directory, starttls

I am using Oracle 19 default dbms_ldap package to connect to Microsoft Active directory.
I am trying to implement LDAP channel binding requirements as per advisory explained [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirements-march-2020/bc-p/1142307)

I got it working with SSL on port 636 (LDAP over SSL), however our CyberSecurity requires us to implement LDAP over TLS on port 389.

LDAP over TLS is defined in [RFC2830](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2830.txt),
Microsoft [documentation on it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/8e73932f-70cf-46d6-88b1-8d9f86235e81)

Is LDAP over TLS (starttls) on port 389 supported in Oracle DBMS_LDAP package? any documents or advise around it would be great.